# What design pattern should I use to make such dialogs?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, xaml

I want to develop dialog for editing objects that make use of polymorphism. Currently I'm using this pattern:

**MyObject.cs:**

```
using System;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class MyObject
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public MySettings Settings { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class MySettings
    {
        public abstract string GetSettingsString();
    }

    public class MyBoolSettings : MySettings
    {
        public bool BoolSetting { get; set; }

        public override string GetSettingsString()
        {
            return "BoolSetting = " + BoolSetting;
        }
    }

    public class MyStringSettings : MySettings
    {
        public string StringSetting { get; set; }

        public override string GetSettingsString()
        {
            return "StringSetting = " + StringSetting;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.EditMyObjectDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="EditMyObjectDialog" Height="350" Width="350">
    <StackPanel Margin="20">
        <TextBlock Text="Title" />
        <TextBox Name="txtTitle" />
        <RadioButton Name="rdBoolSettings" Content="BoolSettings" IsChecked="True" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
        <CheckBox Name="chBool" Content="True" Margin="20, 0, 0, 20" />
        <RadioButton Name="rdStringSettings" Content="StringSettings" />
        <TextBox Name="txtString" Margin="20, 0, 0, 20"/>
        <Button Content="OK" Click="OK_click" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" Click="Cancel_click" Margin="0, 10" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class EditMyObjectDialog : Window
    {
        public MyObject Result { get; set; }

        public EditMyObjectDialog(MyObject objectToEdit)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txtTitle.Text = objectToEdit.Title;
            if (objectToEdit.Settings is MyBoolSettings)
            {
                rdBoolSettings.IsChecked = true;
                chBool.IsChecked = (objectToEdit.Settings as MyBoolSettings).BoolSetting;
            }
            if (objectToEdit.Settings is MyStringSettings)
            {
                rdBoolSettings.IsChecked = true;
                txtString.Text = (objectToEdit.Settings as MyStringSettings).StringSetting;
            }
        }

        private void OK_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Result = new MyObject() { Title = txtTitle.Text };
            if (rdBoolSettings.IsChecked == true) 
                Result.Settings = new MyBoolSettings() { BoolSetting = chBool.IsChecked == true };
            if (rdStringSettings.IsChecked == true)
                Result.Settings = new MyStringSettings() { StringSetting = txtString.Text };
            DialogResult = true;
        }

        private void Cancel_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**ExternalCode:**

```
var f = new EditMyObjectDialog(myObject);
if (f.ShowDialog() == true)
    myObject = f.Result;
```

I belive there is much better design pattern that uses data binding etc. So basically I have two questions.

1. How to make data binding not to
   modify object until user hits 'OK'?
2. How to correctly handle 'Settings'
   property? What to do when user
   switches setting's type?

Comment: As they always say, the benefit of using patterns is that it easily allows you to get information across to other developers who know of the patterns you refer to. You say, "I am currently using *this* pattern:", but don't specify which one. That leaves us to figure it out by reading through all your code. Either you've invented a new pattern, you don't actually use a pattern, or you could get your point across better by letting us know which one you think it is.

Comment: ok looks like I didn't really understand what 'pattern' really means. What I meant is "my actual code looks similar to simple example below".

Comment: did you find a way to  bind the data to the object only when user hits ok.?

Comment: There are two ways to do it. 1) Use Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit 2) Make a copy of object before editing. Since my objects can be saved and loaded from streams (I can easily make a copy) I use second way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe you're looking for is a combination of DataBinding and DataTemplating. DataTemplating will allow you to define different visual elements for different business objects (in this case `MyBooleanSettings` and `MyStringSettings`. DataBinding will allow the visual elements to update and be updated my the data in the business objects.

Example (xaml):

```
<Window DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:MyObject}">
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Title}" />
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Settings}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:MyObject}">
            <TextBox Text={Binding 
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:MyBoolSettings}>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolSetting}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:MyStringSettings}>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding StringSetting}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ObjectToEdit}" />
</Window>
```

Then in the code behind define:

```
public MyObject ObjectToEdit { get; set; }
```

Finally update your objects:

```
public class MySettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(sting s)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(s);
        }
    }
}

public class BoolSettings : MySettings
{
    bool _value;

    bool BoolSetting
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if(_value != value)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BoolSetting");
            }
         }
    }
}
```

**If however you really need to control when the view and object sync you should use the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property on the corresponding bindings.**

If you want some additional reading I recommend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Answer (score 0):

DataBinding is Simple . You can create an instance of MyObject and assign it to the DataContext property of the Form.

```
this.DataContext=MyObject;
```

And define binding for individual elements.

```
 <TextBox Name="txtTitle" Text="{Binding Path=Title,Mode=TwoWay }" />
```

Setting mode as two way will affect the object as you make change in UI. One way will show the values.

Comment: I understand this kind of binding. See my 2 main questions above.

Answer (score 0):

1. How to make data binding not to modify object until user hits 'OK'?

Create a copy of the MyObject instance. In the Result property get method, return copy if user hit cancel (return unchanged copy) or if user hit OK, return the changed MyObject instance.

1. How to correctly handle 'Settings' property? What to do when user switches setting's type?

Whats the problem?